# Node types not working in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have included a Typescript definition file so that I can program my very basic node express server in Typescript. I have installed the types using:

`npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Sadly, my IDE (VS Code) still doesn't recognise the Node typings:

**server.ts**

```
import * as express from "express";

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello Typescript!')
});

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 3000")
})
```

**errors**

**app.get** Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Function'

**app.listen** Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Function'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will also need types for Express:

> npm install @types/express --save-dev

Comment: This removes the error, and the compiler works, but I don't get autocompletion. `express` is seen as `any` and typing `app.` does not suggest `listen` or `get`. Is this expected behavior? Without type checking there is no reason to use typescipt...